# How to ask for Photos/Media/Files permission in android app

Tags: android, android-permissions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M033.png)
I want my app to ask for Photos/Media/Files permission since a third party library requires it, can anyone tell me which specific permission to ask for.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files, photos and media are saved in storage. Your android app will request permission in the relation of what it requires to do. Add the permissions in your Manifest file.

The permission you require is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you want to save Files with your app too, request:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Android versions from Marshmallow and above require runtime grant of permissions. Run the following

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
PERMISSIONS,
PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FOLDERS);
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access

Answer (score 0):

To read Images, Video, and Audio from phone memory in Android with a target SDK API level of 33, you'll need to follow these steps:

**1. Update AndroidManifest.xml:**

You should declare the necessary permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file. In this case, you need to use the appropriate media-related permissions:

**2. Request Permissions at Runtime:**

In Android, you must also request these permissions at runtime to ensure that your app has the necessary access. You can do this in your activity or fragment:

**3. Handle Permission Results:**

You should also override the onRequestPermissionsResult() method to handle the user's response to the permission request:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

--------------------------------------------------------------
  

    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
    };
    
    // Check if permissions are granted, and if not, request them.
    if (checkPermissions(PERMISSIONS)) {
        // Permissions are already granted. You can now access media files.
        // Implement your logic to read images, audio, and video.
    } else {
        // Request permissions if they are not granted.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FOLDERS);
    }
------------------------------------------------------------
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FOLDERS) {
        // Check if the permissions were granted by the user.
        if (checkPermissions(permissions, grantResults)) {
            // Permissions granted, you can now access media files.
            // Implement your logic to read images, audio, and video.
        } else {
            // Permissions were denied by the user. Handle this situation accordingly.
        }
    }
}
```