# How to ask "Allow access photos, media and files on you device?" on Android 11 (in android studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-11

How to ask permissions like this in Android Studio?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to ask for Photos/Media/Files permission in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266309/how-to-ask-for-photos-media-files-permission-in-android-app)

Comment: if you want an easy way to ask for permissions you should check out this library -> https://github.com/QuickPermissions/QuickPermissions-Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

starting Android 6 there is a feature called [Runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), check out linked doc. permission on the screen is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you want to read files only, without storing)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know to to ask this permission in android version below 10. After the storage update, we got something called scoped storage. I want to access the .Satatuses folder in the whatsApp for my status saver app. I have seen many developers in the play store to use this... But I don't know to do it in android 11...

Comment: when Scoped Storage is enabled there is only one way to get access to these files: [`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access) permission. and you won't get it easily, at first Google Play policy restricts this perm usage only for [file managers, antiviruses, etc.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play)

Comment: Only apps targeting at most Android 10 may (still) inspect other apps folders, but these aren't updated since years... (as GP policy allow publishing updates ony for APKs targetng one OS version below current) If you know about any "up-to-date" app in official Google Play store, which gets access to any not-in-own-scope folder (especially 3rd party app) without mentioned permission you should report it, this is against policy and security, maybe Android dev team should inspect "the way" and fix some bug or workaround

Comment: Btw. that was purpose of this feature introduction: to NOT let other apps digg into some others app "private" data... yeah, I know, this hits also a lot of useful, "fair-playing" apps, thats the policy securing users